# indicate issuse_A depends on issuse_B by in jira

Tags: jira

How do I convey the idea that issuse_B depends on issuse_A? For example, software engineers have to wait for the product manager(s) complete the definition if a module.

Is it common to use **"is blocked by"** to indicate that relationship in Jira?

[image]

Comment: Since Jira is configurable, we cannot really say what option *of the options your administrator decided to configure* you should chose. Ask them.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Jira to have any dependency you like. If your administrator has not configure a link called "Predecessor" or "Reuiqrement" or similar, you should ask them.

"Blocked by" in my opinion is not correct. If your ticket is blocked, something unforeseen happened. You can be blocked by a bug that emerged for example. The fact that this ticket is not the first to do in the plan is not what people normally describe as "block", it's what normally happens.

So again: what link category you pick there depends on *your* Jira instance. If there is none, you can create new one's. "Blocked" normally means an unplanned obstacle, not the planned order of events. Find another one for that.